# Accessing a collection inside of a document in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a document, and inside of it there is a collection called `relatives`. In cloud functions, I have `onUpdate()` listener for this document. Once something is changed, I want to access that collection inside of my document. Also documents in the collection `relatives`.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

---

#### What I have tried

```js
exports.UpdateLocations = functions.firestore.document("users/{userID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userEmail = change.after.data().email;
    const prevLocation = change.before.data().userLocation;
    const currentLocation = change.after.data().userLocation;

    if (prevLocation === currentLocation) return 0;

    if (change.after.data().userType.toString() === "Patient") {
        const userLocation = change.after.data().userLocation;
        const relatives = change.after.data().relatives;

        console.log("User's Current Location: " + userLocation);
        console.log("Relatives : "+relatives );

    }
    return;

});
```

---

I want to access relatives and its documents. So I can search and compare field and update them on purpose.

Comment: Instead of describing in words what you're trying to do, can you show in code what you've already done and where you got stuck? That will make it much more likely that someone can either tell you where you went wrong, or complete it for you.

Comment: The reason why I didn't give a code block is that I basically stuck with accessing a collection in a document. I changed my structure and all my previous code became mess. But If giving it make a difference, I'll add it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a subcollection from a `DocumentSnapshot`, you must first get a `DocumentReference` to the document for that snapshot, and then find the `CollectionReference` under that.

In code:

```
change.after.ref.collection("relatives")
```

In here:

1. `change.after` gives you the `DocumentSnapshot` of the modified document.
2. `change.after.ref` then gives you the `DocumentReference` of that document, so its location in the database.
3. `change.after.ref.collection("relatives")` then gives you the `CollectionReference` to the `relatives` subcollection of the document.

So get data from these subcollections you'll have to actually load that data, it is not already included in the `change` object that is passed to your function.

So if you want to load all relatives for the user that triggered the function, it'd be something like:

```
let relativesRef = change.after.ref.collection("relatives");
return relatives.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((relativeDoc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, doc.data().relativeaccount);
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much Frank. That was what I am looking for.